# StreamCorruptedException while reading an Object from ByteBuffer

Tags: java, object, streaming, bytebuffer, datagram

I am using a java NIO Datagram Channel(in blocking mode). I want to transmit an object from one side to the other. This is what I do on the Sender Side:

```
          ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
          ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
          oos.writeObject(pkt);
          ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(baos.toByteArray());
          while(buffer.hasRemaining())
                 channel.write(buffer);
```

Here `pkt` is my object  of the class `ControlPacket` to be transmitted. On the Receiver side:

```
          ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(8192);
          channel.receive(buffer);
          buffer.flip();
          ByteArrayInputStream bias = new  ByteArrayInputStream(buffer.array(),0,buffer.limit());
          ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bias);
          pkt = (ControlPacket)ois.readObject();
```

However I get `java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 00000094` error on running the code. Cannot figure out what is wrong in the code. I mean, since I flip the buffer after receiving it the pointer that reads it will be reset to 0 position and should go up till the position at which the last byte is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close the ObjectOutputStream before writing the buffer.